# Irregular positions of UICollectionViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there a chance that any of you guys can give me a hint how to create the view the same like I posted below?

[image]

I know that the size I can change in this method:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

But how I can change the positions of each UICollectionViewCell?

Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You have to use a custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout that will give you the possibility to set the `CGRect` for each cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a custom `UICollectionViewLayout` and instantiate your `UICollectionViewController` with the custom layout. For apple reference see: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewLayout_class/

The general architecture of a layout is as follows:

`prepareLayout` In here you do any up front layout calculations to determine where views should be placed inside your collection view. One solution would be to have an array of `CGRect`'s that you update in prepareLayout to represent the positions of elements on screen.

`layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:` This method determines which views show up on screen for the given visible rect. If you have an array of `CGRect`'s like explained above, this is as simple as looping through the array and determining if the visible rect intersects with the calculated cell rect.

`layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:` This method returns `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` for the given indexPath. Depending on your data structure, this could be as simple as grabbing the calculated `CGRect` at the `indexPath`'s `item` and setting it on the layout attributes. Quick hint: Start by calling `[super layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath]` and then modify the `frame` property on the returned attributes.

Last, you'll need to ensure you correctly calculate the `collectionViewContentSize`. Otherwise your `collectionView` will have no idea how big its internal content should be. If the content size is wider than the screen, you scroll horizontal, if its taller then you scroll vertical. It all depends on what you need your layout to do. That said, you can certainly create layouts that don't appear to scroll but use scrolling to trigger layout changes on screen. To do this you need to make sure you take advantage of:

`shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:` This method is called every time there is a bounds change, i.e. scrolling. If you return true, then your `prepareLayout` chain is called every scroll iteration. You have to be careful that your layout logic is fast or you risk running into performance issues, however if used correctly you can create some wonderfully unique layouts!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try

Comment: @MarcinCzerkies Good luck! Any questions feel free to append

Comment: Everything I found here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8vB2TMS2uhE   WWDC session 219  Thanks for help